# Get the new id of the transfer item in Jquery Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use two `ul` in sorting. I create sortable function that can transfer `li` in other `ul` so they can both exchange the item. My problem is I cannot get the exact id of the ul where li is transfer.

**Example Scenario:**

When I drag `Test 1` to second `ul (no2)`, it's transfer but the id I get are `1` (which is the original id of the ul where Test 1 from) then next is `2` (which is the id of the ul where the Test 1 is transfer). **What I need is only the id of the ul where Test 1 is transfer, which is `2`. How to get the exact value?**

Here are my codes:

```
<ul class="connected list no1" id="1">
    <li style="cursor:move;" id="trans_1">Test 1</li>
    <li style="cursor:move;" id="trans_2">Test 2</li>
</ul>

<ul class="connected list no2" id="2">
    <li style="cursor:move;" id="trans_3">Other 1</li>
    <li style="cursor:move;" id="trans_4">Other 2</li>
</ul>

<script>    
    $(function() {
        $('.connected').sortable({
            connectWith: '.connected',
            dropOnEmpty: true,
            update: function(){
                 //alert($(this).parents('ul').attr('id'));
                alert($(this).attr('id'));
            }
        });
   });
</script>
```

Additional:

How to get the id of the transfer `li`?

**UPDATE:**

What I need is to get the `ul id` where `li` is transfer in vice-versa. What I said above is just a sample, it doen't mean that I only want `id=2`. What about if I transfer `Other 1` in other ul which id is `1`. Just like that in vice versa.

Comment: you have the same id `1`, for the `ul` and the `li`. Also, `2` is the id for two elements. Is this a typo?

Comment: a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be very useful.

Comment: @Jai it's not working if I use fiddle. I don't know how to use that. But this is the link where I based the codes. http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gWpfv/1/)

```
$(function() {
    $('.connected').sortable({
        connectWith: '.connected',
        dropOnEmpty: true,
        receive:function(event, ui ){
            alert(ui.item.attr('id'));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See what is your issue, you have a common css class for both `<ul>` `.connected` that's why it gets the both ids. Instead you can target only second `<ul>` which has a css class `.no2` and `bind` the event `sortupdate` and look for its id.

This way:

```
$(function() {
   $('.connected').sortable({
     connectWith: '.connected',
     dropOnEmpty: true
   });

   $('.no2').bind('sortupdate', function(e) {
     alert(this.id);
   });
});
```

Try this and see if this helps.

#### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gWpfv/)

Comment: your answer always get `id=2`, whatever I do. What about if I transfer `Other 1` to other ul where the id is `1`?

Comment: What you've put in fiddle is also the same on me. But my code is not working and I don't know why